# Distribution of the estimate inside the prediction interval while performing linear regression

Tags: regression, confidence-interval, prediction-interval

I would like to clarify how to interpret the prediction interval (PI) that we get while performing linear regression.

- I realize that PI provides us the uncertainty in our estimate of y
  when X = x, while confidence interval (CI) provides us the
  uncertainty in E(y|X = x).
- However, given E(y|X=x) and the PI, can we assume anything about the
  distribution of our estimate of y inside the PI?
- As I understand, we can interpret the estimate of y inside the PI with a t-distribution. But correct me if I am missing something here.

  - If correct, can you point me to a reference which explains it?
  - Similarly, can we interpret the distribution of E(y|X=x) inside CI as t-distribution?